# Compare two objects by two criteria

Tags: java, comparator

I have a class user which contains a boolean field, I want to sort a list of users, I want the users who have the boolean field equals true to be in the top of the list and than I want sort them by their names.
Here is my class :

```
public class User{
    int id;
    String name;
    boolean myBooleanField;
    public User(int id, String name, boolean myBooleanField){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.myBooleanField = myBooleanField;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.id == ((User) obj).id;
    }
}
```

Here is an example to clear what I want :
lets say that I have this collection of users :

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
users.add(new User(1,"user1",false));
users.add(new User(2,"user2",true));
users.add(new User(3,"user3",true));
users.add(new User(4,"user4",false));
Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
        //Here i'm lookin for what should i add to compare the two users depending to the boolean field
        return u1.name.compareTo(u2.name);
    }
});
for(User u : users){
    System.out.println(u.name);
}
```

I want to sort users to get this result :

```
user2
user3
user1
user4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Boolean.compare(boolean x, boolean y)` method first. And since `true` elements are sorted to the beginning of the array, you would use `compare(u2.myBooleanField, u1.myBooleanField)`:

```
@Override
public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
    final int booleanCompare = Boolean.compare(u2.myBooleanField,
                                               u1.myBooleanField);
    if (booleanCompare != 0) {
        return booleanCompare;
    }
    return u1.name.compareTo(u2.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines perhaps?

```
Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
    public int compare(User u1, User  u2) {
        String val1 = (u1.myBooleanField ? "0" : "1") + u1.name;
        String val2 = (u2.myBooleanField ? "0" : "1") + u2.name;

        return val1.compareTo(val2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (u1.myBooleanField) {
    if (u2.myBooleanField)
        return u1.name.compareTo(u2.name);
    return -1;
} else if (u2.myBooleanField) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return u1.name.compareTo(u2.name);
}
```

Comment: its showing 
user1
user4
user2
user3

Comment: Had the signs switched, should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!u1.myBooleanField && u2.myBooleanField){
return 1;
} else if (!u1.myBooleanField && u2.myBooleanField){
return -1;
} else {
//Whatever comparator you would like to sort on after sorting based on true and false
}
```

Take a look at what the Java [compareTo()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_compareto.htm) method returns. In my above example, we first sort based on true and false, and then, if the myBooleanField is equal for both users, you can sort based on some other property.

Comment: i think you mean else if (u1.myBooleanField && !u2.myBooleanField)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to seperate top users from the rest

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> list = users.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Info::getMyBooleanField);
```

Select top users and sort them by name

```
List<User> topUsers = list.get(true);
topUsers.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getName().compareTo(u2.getName()));
```

Select of the rest of users and sort them by name:

```
List<User> restUsers = list.get(false);
restUsers.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getName().compareTo(u2.getName()));
```

And here is the final list

```
topUsers.addAll(restUsers );
users=(ArrayList<User>)topUsers;
```

Comment: @user3578325 Any comments letting me know if the above solution works for you?