# The default (natural) sorting order is: Country and then Week

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, comparable

Implement the class: `WeeklyDataProper` that extends the class `WeeklyData`.

Requirements:

- The default (natural) sorting order is: Country and then Week
- The class could be properly used in a `HashSet` collection. Two objects are considered equal if they have the same Country and Week attributes.

**How can I do the first part of the question? by `compareTo` method?**

Right now the result is:

```
int week, String country
```

I need :

```
String country, int week
```

Comment: How to write a two-criteria compareTo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30041805/14215102

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java comparator: Two ordering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959072/java-comparator-two-ordering-criteria)

Comment: @Pirate: The natural order of a class is defined by implementing [java.lang.Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and not by using java.util.Comparator. Although the logic is similar since the question requires implementing a natural order in the class the linked question doesn't really fit 100%.

Answer (score 1):

First, `HashSet` [does NOT maintain any order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time

---

The implementation of a `SortedSet` is `TreeSet` which may use a natural order for objects implementing `Comparable` interface (thus implementing `compareTo` method), or a custom comparator via constructor [`public TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-)

So, class `WeeklyDataProper` may implement `Comparable` interface as follows (null checks omitted here):

```java
public class WeeklyDataProper extends WeeklyData implements Comparable<WeeklyDataProper> {
    // getters getCountry / getWeek implemented in the parent
    // ...

    @Override
    public void int compareTo(WeeklyDataProper that) {
        int result = this.getCountry().compareTo(that.getCountry());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = Integer.compare(this.getWeek(), that.getWeek());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, it may be a bit redundant to implement a separate subclass just to sort the set of `WeeklyData`, therefore the sorted set of `WeeklyData` may be retrieved with the custom comparator:

```java
SortedSet<WeeklyData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(
    Comparator.<WeeklyData>comparing(WeeklyData::getCountry)
        .thenComparingInt(WeeklyData::getWeek)
);
```